# sha-1 implementation in windows c

Tags: c, licensing, sha1

I search for a quick way of calling a sha-1 function in WINDOWS c.
I tried openssl, but I found no current windows static lib file to download (libcrypto.lib), compiling from source is no quick option for me.

On the website http://www.packetizer.com/security/sha1/ I found a c implementation of sha-1 (Paul E. Jones).

It is only one c file (sha1.c) with 370 lines of code and one header file, so it seems pretty easy to include into my source code.

Concerning this implementation I have the following question:

1) The source code is copyrighted under FPL (Freeware Public License).
I have looked at http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical for Freeware Public License, but I did not find it.

The licence file in the source says:

```
This software is licensed as "freeware."  Permission to distribute
this software in source and binary forms, including incorporation 
into other products, is hereby granted without a fee.  THIS SOFTWARE 
IS PROVIDED 'AS IS' AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, 
INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY 
AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  THE AUTHOR SHALL NOT BE HELD 
LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES RESULTING FROM THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EITHER 
DIRECTLY OR INDIRECTLY, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, LOSS OF DATA 
OR DATA BEING RENDERED INACCURATE.
```

So it seems that this license is permissive like BSD, MIT or Apache license.
Is this right? Or is the license similar to GPL or LGPL?

2) Does somebody know if this is a reliable implementation?

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Reads like BSD-ish license to me. If you're really concerned though, the only correct answer is to consult a lawyer

Comment: If you want to be Windows only, there is sha-1 hashing builtin, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379908(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please note that SHA-1 is (theoretically) broken, if you are going for a new implementation, you're advised to go for SHA-2.

Comment: I doubt that this is even an open source license, since it doesn't say anything about the right to modify the code. I personally tend to trust the OpenBSD folks when it comes to crypto; check out [their version of SHA-1](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/hash/sha1.c?rev=1.22) (public domain -- no idea if it will build in Windows).

Comment: @larsmans: Thank you. I will try to compile that for windows!

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec: you're welcome. Make sure you get the header from the same directory, and check out the [API docs](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sha1&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / copyright / legal issues, not programming or software development. See [the [help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 2):

1) It looks like you are able to include it in your program yes. The license does not say anything about modifying the code, so you should refrain from doing so (but seeing as it's a cryptography thing, that's good advice anyway).

2) no idea